# Wordpress redirects single post permalink to the front-page.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

Having a strange wordpress custom theme issue that I can't crack.

I have a custom post type 'artists' that I am displaying posts for that include a link with the_permalink();

I expect this permalink to take me to the template that I have named single-artists.php -- but instead it takes me to front-page.php every time, even though the link in the browser is the correct permalink that should take me to the single post page.

I have refreshed my permalinks in settings several times, and I have loaded the page and flushed my cache/removed cookies. Still going to front-page.php, no matter what post I click on, even though the permalink does change each time.

Anything else I should be doing? AFAIK the naming convention for single-artists.php is correct as the post type IS artists.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic case of me being a beginner, I hadn't noticed that my posts had been hidden from public. Setting public to true (like below) fixed it. If there's any other newbies who run into this hopefully this helps you!

```
function create_artist_post() {
  $args = array(
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'Artists',
      'singular_name' => 'Artist'
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'menu-position' => 20
  );
  register_post_type('artists', $args);
}

add_action('init', 'create_artist_post');
```